# discord.py cannot retreive attachment in dm chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

The error code is:

```
await message.attachments.save('image.png')
```

When I'm trying to run the code, I caught the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'save'
```

The documentation shows that the attachment class should has the save attribute. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.save

However, when I run my bot the attribute doesn't work.

The whole function code:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.dm_only()
    async def post_pic(self, ctx):
        guild = await self.client.fetch_guild(self.guildID)
        if await guild.fetch_member(ctx.message.author.id) is not None:
            async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):
                await message.attachments.save('image.png')
            image = discord.File('image.png')
            self.webhook.send(file=image)
            await ctx.send('Message sent anonymously!')
        else:
            await ctx.send('Message failed to send. Access denied.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering this error because you're trying to use the `save()` function on a **list** of attachments, not just a single one. If you want to save just the first attachment you can do this:

```
await message.attachments[0].save('image.png')
```

If you want to save every attachment a user sends in the one message:

```
attachments = await message.attachments
for index in range(len(attachments)):
  attachment = attachments[index]
  attachment.save('image'+index+'.png')
```